# PHPSID remain available even if the session is closed

Tags: php, session

in my page I create a session, which is correctly available:

```
print_r($_SESSION);   -->  Array ( [favcolor] => blue [animal] => dog [time] => 1623858503 )
print_r($_COOKIE);    --> Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 844a8b3a5dd0365cc80c4802f7a3a6cb )
```

Then, I close the session with following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION);
?>
```

Now, the session seems closed, as the variables are unset, but PHPSID is still there:

print_r($_SESSION);   -->  Array ( )
print_r($_COOKIE);    --> Array ( [PHPSESSID] => 844a8b3a5dd0365cc80c4802f7a3a6cb )

```
the session should be closed so the SID should be removed as well?
```

Comment: `$_COOKIE` contains the cookies received during the request. That doesn’t change retroactively by unsetting the session variable.

Answer (score 0):

Unsetting the session simply removes the internal data you maintain about that user, which is stored in your server. The ID of the session is still maintained in the user's cookies. If you want to remove it you can do it manually

```
setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time() - 86400, '/');
```

Furthermore, when removing the session, you should use the function `session_destroy` instead of unsetting the array.